# How can i get share count of each posts(PHOTO) using PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-share

I post photo from my web app on my wall.My requirment is:-> If someone shared my post then Share counts should be display on my app .
 For ex:- i post text "GM" and two peoples shared this then it will be display like "GM By all jow shared by user1,user2"

```
            $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );
            $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/1414782558825287/sharedposts');
            $response = $request->execute();
            $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($graphObject ); echo "</pre>"
```

it return array in which [story] having value "User1 shared your story" & [story_tags] having detail about "User1"
But two peoples share this so why this showing only one name....
My access token have read stream and public action permissions.
i also used via graph API explorer but it show empty How can i get correct response.Thanks

Comment: If any one have solution please post it.